Last Error Failed in resolving configuration. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL
When I tried in dms to load data from mysql to s3.
Then task fail and show this Error:
Last Error Failed in resolving configuration. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL.

I think there exists more information like just a error message.

You can find more info on DMS errors if you filter the Task's Log Group Events--> %]E:% <--Try this
